# How to simplify future result handling in Akka/Futures?

Tags: scala, akka, future

I want to simplify my `for comprehension` code to make it as simple as possible.

Here is the code

```
case object Message

class SimpleActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Message => sender ! Future { "Hello" }
  }
}

object SimpleActor extends App {

  val test = ActorSystem("Test")
  val sa = test.actorOf(Props[SimpleActor])

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(2.seconds)

  val fRes = for {
    f <- (sa ? Message).asInstanceOf[Future[Future[String]]]
    r <- f
  } yield r

  println {
    Await.result(fRes, 5.seconds)
  }

}
```

Is it possible to get rid of this part

```
.asInstanceOf[Future[Future[String]]]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `pipeTo` function which is all about passing a `Future` between Actors. See [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future) on ask patterns.

```
myFuture pipeTo sender
```

The return type of your ask will be `Future[String]` in your case, which as your comment below asks will need the `mapTo[String]` to actually get the result type to be a `String`. Thus your for-comp could be ditched and directly called:

```
 val fRes = (sa ? Message).mapTo[String]
```

Comment: You mean I need to change receive function to `def receive = { case Message => Future("Hello").pipeTo(sender) }` and map result in for-comp like this `for { f <- (sa ? Message).mapTo[String] } yield f`, right?

Comment: @Finkelson yes, essentially. `pipeTo` makes the message return "flattened" such that you will only get a `Future`.

Comment: Well, it's interesting. Thanks.